How to I connect to AWS EC2 trough SSH?
I have the BITNAMI Lamp stack installed on an EC2 instance on AWS. I'm trying to connect with SSH to upload Forum software. I have the correct key pair. I'm not quite sure what the security profiles should be, but I'm not getting through the SSH.
I use the following command in the terminal.
ssh -i "correctKey.pem" admin@ipaddress.amazonaws.com
The admin is the correct user as it is Debian based distro. What should the security profiles on inbound and outbound be? I suspect that is blocking SSH
